# Beforeunload needs some interaction with the web page before it fires on closing the page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am experimenting with the `beforeunload` event. Here is the example straight from MDN:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.returnValue = '';
        });
     </script>
     <body></body>
</html>
```

Upon pressing F5 (or closing the tab/browser), the browser is supposed to ask whether I really want to leave the page before the page is actually closed.

And it does. But it does so only after *some* interaction with the web page has taken place *before* e.g. F5 is pressed. By interaction I mean for example clicking anywhere into the window or pressing any key on the keyboard.

If I hit F5 immediately after loading the page *without* clicking or pressing some key, the page closes without the browser asking.

Can someone explain this?

EDIT: This has been tested with Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

Comment: While F5 press in Chrome and Edge it asks for Reload site. Whereas in Firefox it is asking only after an interaction.

Comment: In MDN there is a **Note:** To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.